# Set Keyword Status in log to Not Run

Tags: robotframework

I'm currently implementing some tests that run on some of our testing devices. Not all our devices have the same capabilities so only some keywords can pass depending on which device the test is ran on. We are able to determine during the run if a device can run the specific keywords and we skip them when needed.

The issue I'm trying to solve is that when we call `Run Keyword If`, in the log it appears as the keyword passed. I would prefer to have the keywords we're skipping to come up as grey in the log with the status of **Not Run**. The `IF` statement looks better but has the `IF` command then that needs to be expanded to see what wasn't run. If there is a keyword such as Don't Run Keyword and that sets the status to **Not Run** then that would be ideal for getting a quick glance at the log and knowing what was or wasn't tested.

Comment: There's also "Skip If" keyword -- maybe that fits better  ?

Comment: I took a look at the Skip If keyword, but that finishes the entire test. I would like to be able to continue the test but just skipping the single keyword and the log stating that it was skipped (Not Run).